# Is there a safe way to allow an app's user to create custom properties/getters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter

Consider a standard getter:

```
const data = {
  a: 10,
  b: 1,
  val: 12,
  get computedProperty () {
    // call this a formula:
    return this.a * this.b * this.val
  }
}
```

Is there a 'safe' way to allow this formula to be set by an **app's user**?

That is, they must be able to pull properties of the object to use within the calculation of the computed property (getter).

I'm aware that eval() is frowned on for obvious uses.

I had thought of allowing the user to specify a string that could be interpolated:

`${this.a} * ${this.b} * ${this.val}`

... but is this any better since it could still allow for arbitrary code execution?

How have others solved this dilemma? I couldn't find any good references or examples.

Comment: Having more details about this app might help in giving suggestions. For example, you could create a UI where the user picks available properties from a dropdown and then picks operations that can be applied to those properties. But that could be overkill for your situation.

Comment: It would be best to provide all the methods and properties that the user can/should use.  Then they can write the calculation using them.

Comment: If it's just the current user of the app who controls the formula, `eval` isn't that unsafe actually.

Comment: @Bergi : so if that's true, then I guess I also shouldn't be concerned about arbitrary code execution into interpolated strings either then, in which case I guess I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always create a custom validator to validate the formula, and evaluate it only if it is a valid formula. Have created one such custom validator for you

```
const data = {
  a: 10,
  b: 1,
  val: 12,
  validateOperation: function(operation) {
    operation = operation.replace(/this./g,"");
    //Turn all non single-character variables to single character this way
    operation = operation.replace(/val/g,"c");
    var operands = ["(",")","*","/","+","-"];
    var chars = ["a", "b", "c"];
    var buff=[];
    var valid = true;

    //Run a loop over all the characters to check if same variables or operands don't come back to back. Else, it is an invalid formula
    for (var i = 0, len = operation.length; i < len; i++) {
      var char = operation.charAt(i);
      if(operands.indexOf(char) != -1) {
        if(buff.length) {
            //Only "(" or ")" can come back to back
            if(operands.indexOf(buff[buff.length-1]) != -1 && ["(",")"].indexOf(char) == -1 && ["(",")"].indexOf(buff[buff.length-1]) == -1) {
            valid = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      else if(chars.indexOf(char) != -1) {
        if(buff.length) {
            if(chars.indexOf(buff[buff.length-1]) != -1) {
            valid = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        valid = false;
        break;
      }
      buff.push(char);
    }

    return valid;
  },
  computedProperty: function(operation) {
    // call this a formula:
    operation = operation.replace(/ /g, "");
    if(this.validateOperation(operation)) {
        return eval(operation);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  }
}

var operation = "this.a * this.b * this.val";

alert(data.computedProperty(operation));
```

Basically, it is an extensible and simple formula evaluator, which also checks whether the characters given in the formula matches your supported object variables.